# draw a B+ tree in latex

Tags: latex

Is there some way to draw a B+ tree in latex? It would look something like the picture below (ignoring the animations)

[image: Example of B+ tree]

Comment: Note that the question was asked again and answered at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/how-do-i-draw-a-b-tree-in-latex/243496

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PGF/Tikz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) to draw vector graphics with latex. I was satisfied with this latex package. It has a very detailed [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) with many examples. Chapter 11.6 of the manual gives a *Special syntax for Specifying Trees*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to draw the B+ tree directly in LaTeX, but it's definitely possible to include an image. With GraphicX installed, insert `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the header and `\includegraphics{imagefilename}` and the body. See this [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) on LaTeX for more information.