# Does the following code leaks memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

The code is as follows:
I am freeing the `btreeRight` after assiging the pointer to the `root->pointers[0]` which hold the pointer of similar node.After freeing it my program is unstable and not getting the balanced btree. Could you please let me know if i am freeing the memory correctly? If not please suggest how would I free it?

```
         int order =5;

         typedef struct BTREE_HELP {
        //
        }*BTREE,BTREE_NODE;

       BTREE  btree_Start(void){
       BTREE TempBtreeNode;
       TempBtreeNode = malloc(sizeof(BTREE_NODE));
       TempBtreeNode->keys=malloc((order-1) * sizeof(int));
       TempBtreeNode->pointers=malloc((order) * sizeof(void *) );

       TempBtreeNode->isLeaf = FALSE;
       TempBtreeNode->numKeys = 0;
       TempBtreeNode->parent = NULL;
       TempBtreeNode->next = NULL;
       return TempBtreeNode;
         }


      BTREE btree_NewRoot(int key,BTREE btreeRight) {
      BTREE root;
      root = btree_start();
      root->keys[0] = key;
      root->pointers[0] = btreeRight;
      root->numKeys++;
      root->parent = NULL;
      btreeRight->parent = root;
      free(btreeRight->keys);
      free(btreeRight->pointers);
      free(btreeRight);
      return root;
      }
```

Comment: have a look at [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar and return here if you have problems with identifying the memory leak!

Comment: Freeing `btreeRight` after assigning it to something is pretty much a guaranteed crash. I don't know how to fix this for you because I don't know what `btree_NewRoot` is intended to do.

Comment: **btree_NewRoot** generates a new root incase the root is  filled or during the deletion process the elements of btree gets deleted and a new root is required to generated. I am just getting doubt if i am following the proper way of deallocating memory. The valgrind does not show the memory leak at this module **bplus_NewRoot** but my tree gets imbalanced after freeing this memory.

Comment: So, what happens to all the subtrees originally held by `btreeRight->pointers`?

Comment: Lets take a case, if you are familiar with the **B+** tree than you  would be easily able to imagagine, if the root gets filled with the keys and one of the subtree also gets filled and needs to splitted. Then the key also gets updated in the root and root also gets spliited . In this case a new root needs to be generated holding its subtree.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878286/draw-a-b-tree-in-latex links might help you to understand what i mean to say

Comment: Your btree_NewRoot function is not returning a new root (I am assuming a typo and that you meant to return root). In the case where you return root, the root->pointers[0] is now pointing to free'd memory. If you access that outside of this function I am pretty sure bad things happen. Maybe I am missing something from the code flow here, or there is something else you are not showing, but you assign btreeRight to the pointers[0] member of root, you then free the memory associated with btreeRight and never set root->pointers[0] to point to something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. That was the typo, it returns root. Actually i want to assigned the **btreeRight** i'e want to make the right branch of the root.In case of this scenario, do you think there is memory leak?I mean, I should not free the btreeRight node?

Comment: the root in the above commnet stands for the new root.

Comment: @thetna - Three of us have all pointed out this issue (see @Ed's answer, @Marcelo's comment, and my own), you are freeing btreeRight after assigning it to root. We don't know the rest of your code to say whether you should be freeing it or not, but it sure looks like you shouldn't. The issue isn't a memory leak, its that you are releasing memory too early. You are calling free on an object that you assigned to your new root, then passing that new root back. Your app will be unstable as soon as code downstream from this tries to access `pointers[0]` from the root you returned.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have a memory leak. But why are you freeing the memory? You are storing the `btreeRight` in the `root`.

Perhaps better indentation would not go amiss though.